# Ordering <div>'s according to screen/window orientation

Tags: html, screen-orientation

I was wondering about a way to order divs according to screen orientation in mobile devices or window size in desktop computers. I have two div's and I was wondering if there's a way to modify their behavior depending on the distribution of the browser's available screen.

For instance when, they're in a horizontal position I want them to behave like this:

```
 ----------------  ----------------
|                ||                 |
|                ||                 |
|                ||                 |
|      div1      ||      div2       |
|                ||                 |
|                ||                 |
|                ||                 |
 ----------------  -----------------
```

when they're in a vertical position, like this:

```
 ---------------- 
|                |
|                |
|                |
|      div1      |
|                |
|                |
|                |
 ---------------- 
 ---------------- 
|                |
|                |
|                |
|      div2      |
|                |
|                |
|                |
 ----------------
```

I'd love to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS media query!

It allows you to specify what CSS you want applied under certain conditions (in this case, changes in window dimensions).

Check out this link:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

What I would suggest is do all of your general styling at the top of your CSS file, then apply the media queries at the bottom. For your case, within each media query, you would specify the behavior/positioning you want for that specific scenario.

Sample Usage:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) { ...css... }
```

The above statement means, for all resolutions UP TO 980px, apply this styling. If you do something like:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) { ...css... }
```

This will apply the given CSS for all resolutions from 320px up to 480px.

Similarly, only applying a min-width of XX will apply a given CSS for all resolutions XX and above.

Comment: seems lots of typing but very accurate and tidy. That's what I'm using if I don't have a better option.

Comment: "Seems like a lot of typing." If you are referring to the link I provided; understand that you don't NEED to use all of that. The link provides all the different resolutions that are standard for your typical devices. You simply need to pick the ones you think you'll need, and apply the CSS you want. IMO, you can't get much less typing than that, because all it virtually requires is a single line per case. And yes, it is very readable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply float them, if the screen is too narrow, they'll drop down appropriately.

```
div {
    float:left;
}
```

If you wanted them stacked for mobile only. detect your mobile browser and append .mobile to your body, or load a mobile css file completely.

```
div {
    float:left;
}

.mobile div {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Almost two years later, and much more experience acquired from when I answered this question ... I can very assuredly say ... this was the better, cleaner answer :-) I hope people read more than just selected answers.